# How to schedule a batch file via Task Schduler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-s3, task, scheduled-tasks

[image]I have a batch file which syncs a local folder with AWS s3 bucket. When I run the batch file directly, the sync completes without any issues. But when I scheduled a task to schdule this batch file, the sync doesn't happen and new logs aren't copied. I can see in the Last run results "The operation completed successfully.(0x0)".

My current task configuration is given below:

```
Action: Start a program.
Program/Script: D:\...\...\Script.bat
```

The script includes the below command:

```
aws s3 sync  s3:\... D:\Logs\
```

I have also tried with

```
Program/script: cmd.exe 
Arguments: /c start "" "D:\...\...\Script.bat
```

but no luck.

I have given highest priviledges as well.

Please help.

Regards,

Mitesh Agrawal

Comment: `aws` is not a command, it's probably the base name of an executable file. You've not provided sufficient information about your scheduled task for us to assist you. Yu could provide more information by providing the output from `SCHTASKS /Query /V /TN taskname`

Comment: @Compo I have installed aws cli. Post this `aws` is taken as a command. And the script when ran manually works without any issues. Please help.

Comment: @Compo I have added the snap of SCHTASKS plz check and help.

Comment: `aws` is not a command, it is only considered to be a command if there's an executable file with a base name of `aws` and an extension which is listed under `%PATHEXT%`, in the current working directory, or any path listed under `%PATH%`, or in certain parts of the Windows registry. The safest way to run an executable file is to use its fully qualified path and extension, with an unknown current directory, or its relative path and extension with a known current directory. Your `schtasks /query` output doesn't stipulate a `Start In` location, and your provided command or arguments don't either!

Comment: In addition, if you're running a batch file, it shouldn't need to be run as an argument to `cmd.exe`, via the `start` command either. Also, if that's the content of your batch file, you don't even need a batch file, you could simply use for example `"%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe"` as your command, and `/K` or `/C` followed by `"%ProgramFiles%\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\aws.exe" s3 sync  …` as your arguments.

Comment: @Compo: It is still not working. It gives the return code 1. And no files are getting synced. Why the script works when ran directly and not the task? I am unable to figure out this.